# Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I built a Shiny App. <strike>It runs fine locally, but when run using shinyapps.io,</strike> I get this error in the shinyapps.io log: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function".

I use select quite a bit. Here are some examples

```
output$columns <- renderUI({
        req(input$df_input)
        df_input = read.csv(input$df_input$datapath,
                            header = T)
        df_unk_only = select(df_input, contains("ca"), contains("uzn"))
        selectInput("unknown", "Select unk:", choices = colnames(df_unk_only))

df_input = read.csv(input$df_input$datapath, header = T)

        unknown <- df_input %>% select(input$unknown)

        miles <- df %>% select(starts_with("mi"))
```

Another related topic said that a package might mask the select function? I'm using these. I changed library to require to see if that was the issue. it wasn't.
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(psych)
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(DT)

edit: nevermind, the app no longer runs fine locally. i'm not sure how I ran it so many times before.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right data path? When you deploy your app files can only be loaded from the server. To access files from the server you could make a new folder in your .app directory called "www" and put your file in there. You can then access the file with "www/filename.csv".

Comment: i didn't realize that was a thing. right now i have ```fileInput(
                              "df_input",
                              "Upload CSV File",
                              multiple = F,
                              accept = ".csv"),
                          mainPanel(tableOutput("df_output"))  and  output$df_output = renderTable({
        req(input$df_input)
        
        df_input = read.csv(input$df_input$datapath,
                           header = T) ```  do you know of a good example that shows how to store the csv in server then access it?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else gets this error--it was because I was trying to select from a non-existent dataframe.

```
miles <- df %>% select(starts_with("mi"))
```

needed to be

```
miles <- **df_input** %>% select(starts_with("mi"))
```